# TortoiseSVN unknown username *******

Tags: tortoise-svn

I am connecting with a VPN with OpenVPNGUI and when I ask to do a generally task with tortoiseSVN (Update, Commit...) it gives me the error in the title "Unknown username *****" (Of course the asterisk is the name of the user).
When I access the VPN shared folder it told me that it is ok with the checked symbol (Green circle with ok symbol). It never asked me to add authentications so I can't use the clear button.

If someone have solved my problem please answer.
p.s I am on windows 7 by the way.